# PostgreSQL: is it possible to ALTER TABLE and INSERT to it within a single transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, insert, alter

My use case is the following: I'm working on periodical data imports to a PostgreSQL database where some external data has to be imported at regular intervals.

The caveat is the structure of the data might change from one import to the other, therefore I'm truncating + dropping all columns on every import before inserting the new data.

I would like to wrap the entire operation within a single transaction, so in case something goes wrong, the transaction would be rolled back and the old data would still be accessible (lesser of two evils kind-of-thing).

As an example, here is what a data import statement might look like:

```
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "date"
ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "column1"
ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "column2"

ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "date" date DEFAULT NULL
ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column1" text DEFAULT NULL
ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column2" text DEFAULT NULL
ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column3" text DEFAULT NULL

INSERT INTO "external_data" ("date","column1","column2","column3") VALUES ('20170523','Berlin','Chrome','1'),('20170524','Berlin','Chrome','2')

COMMIT
```

This is currently not working. The INSERT statement gets stuck because, when it's called, the table is still locked from the ALTER TABLE statement that preceded it.

Is there any way to achieve this within Postgres transactions or should I give up and go for some other solution application-side?

Comment: Add the new columns.  Populate them.  Then remove the old columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the quick answer. I'm pretty sure the problem would persist as adding the new columns would require an ALTER TABLE statement, which in turn would lock the table preventing the INSERT from being executed.

Comment: `This is currently not working` - Do you get any error message ?

Comment: This cannot work well because of a lack of semicolons.There are no other reasons for the transaction to fail.

Comment: @OtoShavadze nope, as I wrote the last statement just hangs forever waiting for the table.

Comment: @klin you might be right on this! I'm doing all of this within rails which for some reason does not add semicolons in its create column method.. I'll have to find a way to monkey-patch it I guess, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is currently not working. The INSERT statement gets stuck
>   because, when it's called, the table is still locked from the ALTER
>   TABLE statement that preceded it.

No, a transaction can't lock itself that way. The INSERT would be blocked if it was initiated by another transaction, but not by the one that already has a strong lock on the object. There is no problem in dropping the column and doing a subsequent INSERT in the same transaction.

The reason why it seems to be stuck is probably, as mentioned in the comments, that if you feed the sequence of queries from the question to an interactive interpreter,  it would not execute any query at all, because there is no indication of the end of any query. If the interpreter is `psql` this sequence lacks either semi-colons or a `\g` meta-command at the end of queries.

A SQL query by itself does not need a semi-colon at its end, it's only when several queries can be submitted together that it's required.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes. It is posible to alter table and insert inside of one transaction

You can see the example in http://rextester.com/OTU89086

### But. Warning you cannot do many drop/add columns

There are a limit of how much columns you can add (even if you are dropping others). If you do a lot You get:

```
54011: tables can have at most 1600 columns
```

You can see that problen here:

```
--PostgreSQL 9.6
--'\\' is a delimiter

select version() as postgresql_version;

drop table if exists "external_data";

create table "external_data"( 
    "date" date,
    "column1" integer,
    "column2" text,
    "column3" boolean
);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

create or replace function do_the_import()
  returns text
  language plpgsql as 
$body$
begin
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "date";
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "column1";
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "column2";
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" DROP "column3";

  ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "date" date DEFAULT NULL;
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column1" text DEFAULT NULL;
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column2" text DEFAULT NULL;
  ALTER TABLE "external_data" ADD "column3" text DEFAULT NULL;

  INSERT INTO "external_data" ("date","column1","column2","column3") VALUES ('20170523','Berlin','Chrome','1'),('20170524','Berlin','Chrome','2');

  return current_timestamp::text;
end;
$body$;

select count(do_the_import()) from generate_series(1,1000);

COMMIT;
```

Try it here: http://rextester.com/RPER86062